# Correct IHttpClientFactory implementation with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

In [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0), in the **Named Clients** example, they retrieve an `HttpClient` from the IoC container:

```
var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("GitHub");
```

In the **Typed Clients** example, the service that they register as an `HttpClient`, `GitHubService`, creates its own `HttpClient`:

```
public class GitHubService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public GitHubService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        ...
```

Then, of course, to use the `HttpClient`, a consuming class would create an instance of `GitHubService`.

This leaves me with two questions:

1. In the *Typed Clients* example, is `GitHubService` actually implementing `IHttpClientFactory` since it is creating its `HttpClient` directly?
2. Also in the *Typed Clients* example, what role is the IoC container playing?  Couldn't the same be done without registering `GitHubService` with the IoC container at all?

Comment: If GitHubService implemented IHttpClientFactory, then you would see this code: public class GitHubService **: IHttpClientFactory**

Comment: "GitHubService, creates its own HttpClient" - I think this is at the root of your confusion. GitHubService *does not* create an HttpClient - go through the article, you'll see that this isn't stated anywhere. The HttpClient is externally injected, and GitHubService just stores whatever instance was provided to it. You also say "to use the HttpClient, a consuming class would create an instance of GitHubService", but it's exactly the other way around - for calling code to use a GitHubService instance, it has to either create an HttpClient first, then pass it to GitHubService constructor, or 1/2

Comment: ...or it has to receive a GitHubService instance from some other code that already has it or knows how to make one (in this case, the DI container). [for clarity: talking about the Typed Client example] 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović thanks for your response.  You're right about the `HttpClient` in `GitHubService`; I should re-word that.  However, when a new instance of `GitHubService` is instantiated, doesn't the caller have to provide an `HttpClient`?  Otherwise, the caller does not meet the requirements of `GitHubService`'s constructor, no?

Comment: Yes - that's what I wrote above. Whatever code is *directly* creating the `GitHubService` instance (and this code is not necessarily the intended client code), it has to provide an `HttpClient`. In the case where the caller is also the one creating the `GitHubService`, providing an `HttpClient` is also its responsibility. Otherwise, some other code does that work (instantiation), and provides the `HttpClient` to the `GitHubService` constructor - and this is the role that the IoC container plays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing you are missing from the Typed Client example is the way it is instantiated

"The typed client is registered as *transient* with DI"

This means every time it's fetched from the DI container, the DI container creates a new instance. The new instance needs a new httpClient for its construction, which is in turn provided by the DI container via a registered HttpClientFactory.

So to answer your direct questions

1. No, it doesn't create and expose a httpClient.
2. The role of the IoC container is to ensure that the httpClient used is generated from the client factory every time GitHubService.GetAspNetCoreDocsBranchesAsync() is called.

   If you didn't use the container then you would have to manage the lifecycle of the underlying HttpClient yourself.

I'm guessing this example is provided to give you guidance on how to integrate this popular way of writing a service class which takes a httpCient as a construction parameter rather than a IHttpClientFactory